# umount multiple mounts under same directory

Tags: mount, unmount

My system has a USB, an sd card and an SSD connected. I mounted all the devices USB(/dev/sdb1), SSD(/dev/sda1) and sd card(/dev/mmcblk1p1) under /mnt. Is there any way to unmount all the devices connected at /mnt?

(*I can do this by performing grep to lsblk/df/mount output and unmounting individual one but I am looking for another easy solution OR by performing 3 times umount /mnt*)

## Update 2

Here is output of lsblk(multiple mountpoints)

```
lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda            8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk 
└─sda1         8:1    0 232.9G  0 part /mnt
sdb            8:16   1  14.7G  0 disk 
└─sdb1         8:17   1  14.7G  0 part /mnt
```

and after performing recursive umount

```
sudo umount --recursive /mnt
lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT 
sda            8:0    0 232.9G  0 disk
└─sda1         8:1    0 232.9G  0 part /mnt
sdb            8:16   1  14.7G  0 disk
└─sdb1         8:17   1  14.7G  0 part
```

Comment: Can you post the output of `mount` and the output (if any) of `sudo umount --recursive /mnt`

Comment: @j-money I have added an update to the question

Comment: Better question. Why are you mounting so many partitions to a single point? This sounds like a bad idea....

Comment: @j-money, I agree with what you are saying. But, let's say some (bad)programs are mounting these devices under the same tree(/mnt) and In my program, when I want to mount my device at /mnt I want to unmount all the existing ones. Hence I want to know is there any easy way of doing.

Comment: Get rid of the program. In this obscure situation, the results are as expected. I do not think there is a way to unmount all mounted points

Answer (score 6):

```markdown
-A, --all-targets
  Unmount all mountpoints in the  current  namespace  for  the  specified
  filesystem.   The filesystem can be specified by one of the mountpoints
  or the device name (or UUID, etc.).  When this option is used  together
  with  --recursive,  then  all  nested  mounts within the filesystem are
  recursively unmounted.  This option is only supported on systems  where
  /etc/mtab is a symlink to /proc/mounts.
```

Is that maybe what you want?  From [`man 8 umount`](https://linux.die.net/man/8/umount).

Comment: This does not work.

Comment: `umount -A --recursive <path>` works.

Answer (score 3):

This one-liner works for me:

```
while [[ $(findmnt /mnt) != "" ]]; do sudo umount /mnt; done
```

Explanation:

If the command `findmnt /mnt` produces non-empty output, something is mounted under `/mnt`. The test checks if the output is empty or not and if the output is not empty, we run `umount /mnt` once. If `findmnt /mnt` produces empty output, nothing is mounted under `/mnt` anymore and we are done.

If you run as *root* you can remove `sudo` from the line. If you run as normal user, you need `sudo` for the `umount`-command, but you need to enter your password only once.

Comment: Seems like it does not find any mounted directories under `/mnt`

Comment: @alper I don't know what you are trying to do, this one-liner is designed to check if anything is mounted on `/mnt` and if so, to unmount it. If you talk about a different mount-point such as  `/mnt/sub`, then you have to adapt the command accordingly.

Comment: I have a folder in my home directory. `/home/user/mount_folder` and there are some mounted directories 2 depth under it, `/home/user/mount_folder/*/mounted_i` //  Seems like it unable to `findmnt` them. As I understand it requires exact folder path of the mounted directory

Comment: @alper Yes, you have to use the correct path to the mountpoint. Feel free to take a look at `man findmnt`.

Answer (score 0):

Try with lazy unmount:

```
sudo umount -l /mnt
```

Comment: This still doesn't unmount all the /mnt mount points. It just unmounts the last mounted device.

Comment: Sorry, try "sudo umount -R /mnt" instead.

Comment: This also works same, just unmounted the last mounted device. The other devices are still mounted. Also, I didn't find the '-R' option in the umount manual.

Comment: please fix your answer as `umount -l /mnt` is **not** what op wants or needs.

Comment: @RushikeshGaidhani, I can make a script for you that will unmount all the devices on /mnt, will this suit your needs? I'll update my answer accordingly to the op answer.

Comment: @CristianVrinceanu, That will be great! But as I mentioned in the question I don't want to grep the output of df/lsblk/mount and find out individual devices which are mounted at /mnt.  here I am looking for an easy to go solution for it.

Comment: The easy solution is to intelligently mount your partitions **not** to the same mount point

Answer (score 0):

You can umount the device itself, wildcards allowed.

```
umount /dev/sda1 /dev/sdb? /dev/sdc*
```

Comment: You'd need to know in which order the partitions have been mounted.